# Disable WordPress trash for one Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible to disable the WordPress trash feature for one custom post type?

The goal would be to have the same functionality as define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0) -- permanent post deletion -- except for one CPT, not site-wide.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 4):

While I wasn't able to come up with a particularly elegant way to do this, I was able to bypass the trash using the wp_trash_post action.

```
<?php
function directory_skip_trash($post_id) {
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'directory') {
        // Force delete
        wp_delete_post( $post_id, true );
    }
} 
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'directory_skip_trash');
```

Essentially when the post is trashed, you trash it again with $force_delete parameter set to true.

This solution could be improved by finding a way to change the word 'Trash' throughout the admin UI for this CPT, but for my particular use-case this works well enough.

Comment: This doesn't fully work for me. When clicking trash it gives the error message "Error in moving to Trash". The post is deleted though, so the only problem is the error message.

Comment: Use the hook `trashed_post` instead of `wp_trash_post` to avoid the error. The hook `wp_trash_post` runs before WordPress it's own takes action to delete the post by moving it to the trash.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `wp_trash_post` action work for me, so I used another approach, replacing the trash link with a delete link.

[`post_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) filters the array of row action links on the Posts list table.

```
<?php
function replace_trash_with_delete( $actions, $post ) {
    if( 'directory' === $post->post_type ){ // Replace 'directory' with your post type
        unset( $actions['trash'] ); // Removes the trash link 

        $deleteUrl = esc_url( get_delete_post_link( $post->ID, '', true ) ) ;
        $deleteLink = '<a rel="nofollow" href="' . $deleteUrl . '">' . __('Delete') .'</a>'; // Creates the new delete link

        $actions = 
            array_slice( $actions, 0, 1, true ) +
            array( 'delete' => $deleteLink ) +
            array_slice( $actions, 1, count( $actions ) - 1, true ); // Adds the delete link to the array of links
    }
} 
add_filter( 'post_row_actions','replace_trash_with_delete', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I found that I needed to use `global $post;` instead of the argument, and this filter must return `return $actions` after the if statement for it to be complete